# can webpack dev-server omit .html extension

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-dev-server

hi guys I have some questions about webpack-dev-server

My webpack build result consists of two html file(index.html / editor.html) each scripting two bundled js files.
Since my dev-server is running on port 80

1. localhost -> render index.html fine
2. localhost/editor.html -> render editor.html fine
   However, is there any way my dev-server renders editor.html from url [localhost/editor] (without html extension showing??)

I noticed that webserver(nginx, apache) config file can control these (please correct me if i'm wrong) but is there anyway i can do this on webpack-dev-server??